# CXF - How to properly configure Spnego with CXF 3.2.6

Tags: java, authentication, cxf, kerberos, spnego

I'm trying to do create a CXF soap web service client to make soap calls with a Kerberos authenticated SharePoint instance.

I import the following:

- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:3.2.6
- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:3.2.6
- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http-hc:3.2.6
- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-security:3.2.6

Here is my java program.

```
import crawler.common.sharepoint.stubs.lists.Lists;
import crawler.common.sharepoint.stubs.lists.ListsSoap;
import org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.TLSClientParameters;
import org.apache.cxf.configuration.security.AuthorizationPolicy;
import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client;
import org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.http.asyncclient.AsyncHTTPConduit;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.http.auth.HttpAuthHeader;
import org.apache.cxf.transports.http.configuration.HTTPClientPolicy;
import org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.KerberosTokenInterceptor;

import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;

public class SharepointKerberosTesterClient {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "/home/ndipiazza/xxxx/spnego-http-client/krb5.conf");
    System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "false");
    System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "/home/ndipiazza/xxxx/spnego-http-client/login.conf");

    String endpoint = "http://win-qbfsb933r5p/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
    Service service = Service.create(Lists.SERVICE);
    ListsSoap soap = service.getPort(ListsSoap.class);
    BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) soap;

    bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(AsyncHTTPConduit.USE_ASYNC,
        Boolean.TRUE);
    bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(
        BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endpoint);

    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(bindingProvider);
    client.getEndpoint().put("org.apache.cxf.stax.maxChildElements", System.getProperty("org.apache.cxf.stax.maxChildElements") != null
        ? System.getProperty("org.apache.cxf.stax.maxChildElements") : "5000000");
    HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();

    AuthorizationPolicy authorization = new AuthorizationPolicy();
    authorization.setAuthorization("SharePoint");
    authorization.setAuthorizationType(HttpAuthHeader.AUTH_TYPE_NEGOTIATE);
    http.setAuthorization(authorization);

    HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
    httpClientPolicy.setAllowChunking(false);
    httpClientPolicy.setAutoRedirect(true);

    TLSClientParameters tlsClientParameters = new TLSClientParameters();
    tlsClientParameters.setDisableCNCheck(true);

    http.setTlsClientParameters(tlsClientParameters);

    http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);

    System.out.println("Size of lists: " + soap.getListCollection().getContent().size());

  }
}
```

If you take a look at this example, http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-kerberos.html#JAXRSKerberos-AuthorizationPolicy there is a special class `KerberosAuthOutInterceptor` that is able to add the Negotiate Authorization headers as required.

But in 3.1.x and 3.2.x versions of CXF that doesn't seem to exist.

Instead there is a https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/rt/ws/security/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/ws/security/policy/interceptors/SpnegoTokenInterceptorProvider.java that I think I am supposed to use.

But I do not know how to use an interceptor provider. Does anyone know how to use this with the programmatic (non-xml) declaration of CXF?

Comment: Hmmm I'm digging in further and I'm thinking this is a SharePoint issue actually.

Comment: This question was invalid. Thanks very much to KyleM for spending time on it anyways. It was sharepoint config related. see my comment on kyle's answer.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint is deployed on IIS, and IIS can definitely do Kerberos authentication. So I doubt it is a SharePoint issue - can you share your insight into why you think so? The way I would debug this is I would start your client with the flag `-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true` (not positive that will work with the class you are using). But try to snoop the header, the server should be sending WWW-Authenticate. The response provided by the client (which you can view in debug logs on the SharePoint server) should be YII for Kerberos or TIRM for NTLM. So you've got a problem with your Kerberos configuration if it starts with TIRM. You'd probably have to enable connection debugging through IIS to view this information.

Comment: sorry it was a big fat false alarm. here is what i did wrong: I added my user `kerberos` in the Central admin -> manage web apps -> User permissions, then tested soap web service with NTLM. All good. So I proceeded to enable kerberos and disabled NTLM. then i did a few tests I think accidentally using the administrator credentials. When I turned on kerberos, turns out you need to delete the existing user from the user permissions and re-add the user. Once I finished that, everything works.